# Help deriving geodesic of $S^2$ by considering small deviations

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

For $s(t)$ the geodesic confined to the surface of a (3D) sphere, how does one get $\|\dot{s}\|^2 s + \ddot{s} = 0$ by setting $\frac{d}{d\delta} \left( \int \|\frac{d}{dt} \frac{s(t)+\delta h(t)}{\|s(t)+\delta h(t) \|}\|^2 dt \right) = 0$ at $\delta = 0$ for any arbitrary (but smooth) $h(t)$?

Is brute-force differentiation of the expression (horribly ugly and I have not succeeded in arriving at the desired expression) the only way to do it?

Thanks!

Edit: Just wanted to clarify that I am asking for how to carry out the calculation using, in particular, the $\frac{d}{d\delta} (...) = 0$ method.
(Thanks to all who have pointed out the ambiguities.)

Oh no! I have just realized that I foolishly left out bits of the derivand! (Was too bogged down by the formatting and clearly wasn't checking properly.) Would the question make more sense now? (Sorry :S)

Comment: Are you asking for an explanation of why this procedure yields geodesics, or asking how to carry out the calculation?

Comment: I know that this post should really be a comment, but someone logged me out of my unregistered account ("Hitchhiker"), which I believe is the reason why I don't see a "Comment" (or something of the sort) button. Anyway, @Zhen Lin, I am asking for the latter -- how to carry out the calculation. Thanks! --Hitchhiker

Comment: Hitchhiker, you might want to register to avoid these troubles.

Comment: @Hitchhiker: this is my understanding. As an unregistered user, you only stay logged in as long as a particular cookie remains on your system, so it's easy to lose access. This will stop being an issue if you register.

Comment: I answered a [similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/53799/1543) a few weeks ago. It'd be nice if you can read it to see if it helps. And if it doesn't, edit your question to reflect where you are having problems.

Comment: @Willie Wong: Thanks for the link. The questions do indeed end up in the same form (up to a sign)! (Wow!) But the ways of getting there are different... I am wondering how I might get there using the $\frac{d}{d\delta}(...)=0$ method. Grateful if you could help me out :)

Comment: @Hitchhiker: I recommend trickery. $\left\| \mathord{-} \right\|^2$ is a lot easier to work with than $\left\| \mathord{-} \right\|$, so we should replace the derivand $y$ by its square. Note that $\frac{d}{dx}\left[y^2\right] = 2y \frac{dy}{dx}$, and so if $y$ is nowhere zero, $\frac{d}{dx}\left[y^2\right] = 0$ if and only if $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$.

Comment: I don't see how you can possibly get $t$ derivatives by differentiating that expression with respect to $\delta$.

Comment: Thanks guys. Unfortunately I made a mistake while typing the question... I have now modified it. Would that make more sense now? (I still need help though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a general piece of advice in response to your assessment of the derivative as "horribly ugly": In this sort of calculation, it simplifies things quite considerably if you keep in mind while differentiating that you're about to set $\delta=0$; then you can immediately drop everything proportional to $\delta$ that you're not differentiating.

Keeping that in mind, taking the derivative with respect to $\delta$ and setting $\delta=0$ yields:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\delta}\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\frac{s+\delta h}{|s+\delta h|}\right)^2\right|_{\delta=0}
&=&
\left.2\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\frac{s+\delta h}{|s+\delta h|}\right)\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\delta}\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\frac{s+\delta h}{|s+\delta h|}\right)\right|_{\delta=0}
\\
&=&
2\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\frac{s}{|s|}\right)\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left(\frac{h}{|s|}-\frac{(h\cdot s)s}{|s|^3}\right)
\\
&=&
2\dot s\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left(h-(h\cdot s)s\right)\;,
\end{eqnarray}$$

where in the end I used $|s|=1$. We can use integration by parts to move the derivative to the first factor to conclude that $\ddot s\cdot (h-(h\cdot s)s)$ must vanish. The second factor is the component of $h$ orthogonal to $s$, so this implies $\ddot s=\lambda s$. We can find $\lambda$ by differentiating $0=s\cdot\dot s$, which yields $0=s\cdot\ddot s+\dot s\cdot\dot s=\lambda s\cdot s+\dot s\cdot\dot s=\lambda+\dot s\cdot\dot s$, so $\lambda=-\dot s\cdot\dot s$, and thus $\ddot s=-(\dot s\cdot\dot s)s$.